# SVG appendChild for element (like path) does not work with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, appendchild

I want to get a path element of a SVG to be drawn as last child, while hovering it. I use the appendChild() method, but it will not work in IE 9,10,11 (but it throws no error there, too).

The shapes should fill red on mousover and yellow on mouseout. But **in IE** the shapes get filled red an **keep red on mouseout**. It seems the mouseout event gets lost somehow after the element has moved to the bottom of the SVG code.

Any help what I have missed or how I can achieve this dynamically?

```js
window.onload = function start() {
    var Shapes = document.getElementsByClassName('kreise');
    for (var b = 0, a = Shapes.length; b < a; b++) {
        Shapes[b].addEventListener("mouseover", up);
        Shapes[b].addEventListener("mouseout", down);
    }
}
function up() {
    var element = this;
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.appendChild(this);
    element.setAttribute('class', 'kreise mouseover');
 } 

 function down() {
    var element = this;
    element.setAttribute('class', 'kreise mouseout');
 }
```

```css
#shape1 {
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}
#shape2 {
 stroke: blue;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}
.mouseover {
 fill:red;
}
.mouseout {
 fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg id="TestSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 268 367">
  <title>Text</title>
   <path id="shape1" class="kreise" d="M172.81,61l1.61.88.74-.88,3.06,1.63,1.47,1.63h4.67l2.34-4,.73,2.38h2.33V60.24l3.82-1.5v-.88l.86-2.26-1.6.75L191,54.85l.24-.88,2.47-.87.74-1.76-3.94,1h-3.07l-.73-2.25-1.6,1.5L182,50.84v-.75l-2.34.75-1.47-1.62-3.06,1.62-.74-1.62-.86.87-.75,2.25.75,2.38-2.34,2.39,2.34,2.38Zm-25.28-10.9-2.34-1.63,3.07-1.63,1.48,2.39h1.59V47.7h1.47l-.73-5.5-1.48-4.77-.11-1.06,1-.31.81-.94.75-1.39.68-.53.45-.14.71,0,1.23.31,1,.09.18-.4.24-1.35V30.2l.36-1.17.62-1.12.93-.85,1.64-.67,1.22-.32.65-.35,1.26-1.26,2.27-1.25.24-.27.15-.44.45-1.93.12-.23,1-.94,1.16-.72.93-1.16.45-2.5.35-.9.24-.94.57-1.2.09-.5-.11-.49-1.65-1-.75-.76V9l.33-.44.75-.41,1.41-.49,1.52-.31.56-.27.9-.09,3-.8,1.22-.45.87-.54.42-.49.48-2,.2-.32,1.26.63,1.76-1.7L187,2l-.27,2.42.65,1,.75.44,1.59.23.89-.23,1.17-1.11.86-.86.87-.26.74.4-.27,1.39,2.48.71,1.22,0,1.49-.32,1.86-.4.27,1.25.48,1,2.11.63.81.67.33,2.6.83,1.43,2.19,2.2-.3,1.2-.94.5-1.07-.32-2.41-1.83-1,.09L202,16.18l.78,1.25.18,1.31-1.28-.28-.81-.63-.74.78.35,2.32-.89,2-1,.18-1.23.36.63,1.57,1.43,2.46.39,1.75.78.94,2.09.89-.33,1.08-.92,1.38,1.19,1.66-.45,1.3-.06,1.08.45,1.2.83.9.12,1.43L203,42.29l-3.17.22-1,.18-1.22.44-1.19-.53-.42,1.07-1.85,1.61.48,1.12,1.46.86-.45,1.34L195,49l-1.05-.14-.95-.31-1.59-.76-.42.67.66,1,2.48,1.07,1.7,1.26.75.22,1.52.58,1.19.67,3.11,1.39,1.67,1.07.89.13-.14.59L203.64,61l3.93,2.38L209,65l5.29-1L213,65.76l-1.6.75-2.22.5L206,71.26l-3.8,2.38-.74,3.89-1.6,1.63L194.44,76V72.77L191.36,72l-1.47-1.5-4.67.75-4.67-1.62-3.06.87-2.34-1.62-3.07-.76-.74-.75V65.76h-6.87l-.49,3.5-.37,3.51h-.74V74.4l-3.8.75-.86.88v1.5l-3.81,1.63-1.6-4-5.27-3.89.73-3.13-3.93-1.62-.74-3.14,3.07-.75V61h-.74l-.73-5.52-.86-2.25,2.33-.88Z"/>
  <path id="shape2" class="kreise" d="M79.97 110.56 81.33 110.25 83.2 106.13 84.4 104.88 85.11 103.67 85.26 103.17 85.29 102.45 85.14 101.65 84.72 100.58 83.74 98.7 83.92 98.21 84.22 97.8 84.46 97.04 84.49 96.82 84.31 95.84 84.22 95.57 83.17 94.22 82.28 93.5 82.37 93.05 82.85 92.07 83.02 91.84 93.29 91.84 95.89 92.29 97.29 92.78 97.85 92.78 99.5 91.49 102.25 90.15 102.69 89.79 102.9 89.38 102.87 88.89 101.32 86.66 101.23 86.39 101.35 85.75 101.56 85.32 102.57 84.05 105.65 80.74 106.51 79.94 107.44 78.78 107.55 78.37 107.55 77.34 106.72 73.8 106.42 71.92 105.17 66.69 104.99 66.38 103.83 65.92 104.3 64.62 104.39 64.13 104.24 63.68 104.07 63.46 103.56 63.24 102.84 63.46 100.46 65.16 99.44 65.56 97.29 66.02 95.83 66.02 95.29 66.19 94.84 66.56 94.36 67.67 94.01 68.12 93.32 68.3 91.89 68.12 91.14 67.76 90.81 67.09 90.45 65.47 89.35 64.71 88.45 63.91 88.42 62.97 89.23 61.09 90.22 59.48 91.41 58.14 92.87 56.2 96.27 53.16 96.69 52.22 96.72 51.78 96.87 51.33 97.59 50.76 98.39 50.66 99.58 50.26 99.53 49.09 99.58 48.69 99.94 48.29 102.25 47.97 104.12 47.07 105.05 46.76 106.21 46.67 107.29 46.8 109.05 46.62 112.07 45.68 113.44 45.46 114.93 45.59 116.51 46.26 117.61 46.58 118.48 46.62 119.35 46.18 120.93 44.83 122.04 44.25 122.66 44.07 124.15 43.94 126.48 43.98 127.67 43.85 127.41 42.55 127.52 42.06 128.46 41.39 128.81 40.72 128.75 40.5 128.6 40.09 127.95 39.69 125.4 39.33 125.05 39.11 124.93 38.66 125.02 36.91 124.81 35.16 124.63 34.36 124.24 33.6 122.96 31.9 122.93 31.59 123.23 30.38 123.68 29.71 124.09 29.3 125.7 28.22 130.27 26.57 133.49 25.94 134.54 25.54 136.22 24.6 136.46 24.78 136.84 25.49 138.16 27.28 138.87 27.82 139.56 28.04 141.14 27.73 141.94 27.73 142.45 27.95 143.49 29.07 143.58 29.48 143.16 31.27 143.05 33.11 143.25 33.78 144.42 35.12 146.9 35.97 149.38 36.37 150.48 36.37 150.59 37.43 152.07 42.2 152.8 47.7 151.33 47.7 151.33 49.22 149.74 49.22 148.26 46.83 145.19 48.46 147.53 50.09 146.66 52.34 144.33 53.22 145.19 55.47 145.93 60.99 146.66 60.99 146.66 62.62 143.59 63.37 144.33 66.5 148.26 68.13 147.53 71.26 152.8 75.14 154.4 79.16 155.13 83.04 157.47 86.18 154.4 91.69 152.07 92.44 152.07 94.06 148.26 98.83 146.66 98.83 144.33 99.58 144.33 102.71 142.12 105.85 135.85 110.61 136.72 113.73 138.2 112.86 138.2 116.12 134.63 116.87 131.32 117.63 129.72 115.5 128.49 113.98 126.77 112.86 124.44 114.5 117.56 112.86 116.82 114.5 111.42 114.5 108.35 111.36 105.28 112.11 105.28 110.61 102.95 110.61 101.36 108.98 98.28 108.98 96.81 112.11 95.21 111.36 93.74 114.5 89.07 115.25 86 113.73 82.94 114.5 78.51 112.23 78.72 111.99 79.38 110.83 79.97 110.56z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the appendChild method, after using this method, the elements were re-appended, and the mouseout event will not fire. Try to remove this part of code, and using the following code:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    var Shapes = document.getElementsByClassName('kreise');
    for (var b = 0, a = Shapes.length; b < a; b++) {
        Shapes[b].addEventListener("mouseover", up);
        Shapes[b].addEventListener("mouseout", down);
    }
}
function up() {
    var element = this;
    element.setAttribute('class', 'kreise mouseover');
 }  

 function down() {
    var element = this;
    element.setAttribute('class', 'kreise mouseout');
 }
```

Then, it will works well on IE 9+. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does not do the trick. I'm searching a way to get the hovered element on top. With your idea it stays down, what can bee seen in your .gif (as the black outline will never overlap the black one when hovered)